# дублирование GET

Tags: php, get

Дорогие друзья, никак не могу разобраться, почему дублируются `get`?

К примеру `lala.ru/?lang=lat?lang=ru?lang=lat?lang=ru`

и

`lala.ru/?g=lala&lang=lat&lang=ru&lang=lat&lang=ru`

для главной страницы `?lang=ru`, а для других `&lang=ru`

```
<?if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {?><a href="?lang=ru">ru</font></a><?}else{?> <a href="<?=preg_replace('/(\&\?)lang\=.*$/i', '$1', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>&lang=ru">ru</font></a><?}?>

$l=$_COOKIE['lang'];

if(($_GET['lang'] && ($_GET['lang']=='ru' || $_GET['lang']=='lat')) || $_POST['langu']){
$l=$_GET['lang'];
if(!$l){$l=$_POST['lang'];}
setcookie("lang", $l);  

}

if(!$l){$l='ru';}

if ($l=='lat') {

$path_html='htmls_lat/';
$arr = array('religion' => ''.$upp['zagalovok_lat'].' lala', 'svadba' => ''.$upp1['zagalovok_lat'].' lalala');

$title = isset($arr[$_GET['g']]) ? $arr[$_GET['g']] : 'xxxxxx';


}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Дублируется, потому, что регулярное выражение меняет не то, что планировалось. В таком варианте

```
preg_replace('/(\&\?)lang\=.*$/i', '$1', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

в запросе заменится последовательность `&?lang=xxx` на часть в скобках – на `&?`. Скобки, вероятно, должны быть квадратными, а замена - пустой строкой. Но вообще это некрасиво, лучше уж брать все GET-параметры и менять значение 'lang', как-то так:

```
$data = array_slice($_GET, 0); // сделали копию всех GET-параметров
$data['lang'] = 'ru';          // lang теперь точно RU
$parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // скрипт отдельно, параметры отдельно
printf( '<a href="%s?%s">ru</a>', $parts['path'], http_build_query($data)); // собрали ссылку, и никаких </font>
```

См. документацию по [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php), [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) и [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php).

Но вообще всё решение и код жуткие, хорошо бы стереть и написать с чистого листа. Переключение языков сайта можно реализовать так:

1. определить какой-то из языков как язык по-умолчанию;
2. выбранный язык держать в сессии и сохранять в Cookies;
3. приоритет: GET-параметр, куки, сессия, по-умолчанию.
4. если есть GET-параметр, транслировать его и дальше во всех ссылках (вдруг, у клиента отключены куки или не держится сессия из-за настроек веб-сервера и php).